# Query does not work inside sp_MSforeachdb

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, if I run this code without the `sp_MSforeachdb` it works fine:

```
SELECT          
    CASE 
        WHEN a.type_desc = 'ROWS' 
            THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN max_size / 128.0 < 0 and growth > 0 
                        THEN 0
                    WHEN growth = 0 
                        THEN CAST(size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
                    ELSE CAST(max_size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
                END
    END AS row_maxsize
FROM          
    sys.database_files a
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.filegroups fg ON a.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
```

But inside my query, it does not work unless I remove the line

```
WHEN growth = 0 THEN CAST(size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
```

Why?

```
--SEMPRE RETORNA 0% SE O DATABASE TIVER UM MDF/NDF COM MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @temp_dbspace_solaire TABLE (
        DATABASE_NAME VARCHAR(100),
        ALLOCATED_LOG_SIZE_MB FLOAT,
        ALLOCATED_ROW_SIZE_MB FLOAT,
        ALLOCATED_TOTAL_SIZE_MB FLOAT,
        USED_ROW_SPACE_MB FLOAT,
        MAX_ROW_SIZE FLOAT,
        MAX_ROW_UTILIZATION DECIMAL(15, 2),
        MAX_LOG_UTILIZATION DECIMAL(15, 2)
    );

    INSERT INTO @temp_dbspace_solaire (database_name, allocated_log_size_mb, allocated_row_size_mb, allocated_total_size_mb,USED_ROW_SPACE_MB,MAX_ROW_SIZE,MAX_ROW_UTILIZATION,MAX_LOG_UTILIZATION)
    EXEC sp_MSforeachdb '
    USE [?];
    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT
            ALLOCATED_LOG_SIZE_MB = CAST(CASE WHEN a.type_desc = ''LOG'' THEN size END * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(12, 2)),
            ALLOCATED_ROW_SIZE_MB = CAST(CASE WHEN a.type_desc = ''ROWS'' THEN size END * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(12, 2)),
            ALLOCATED_TOTAL_SIZE_MB = CAST(size * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(12, 2)),
            USED_ROW_SPACE_MB = CAST(CASE WHEN a.type_desc = ''ROWS'' THEN SIZE/128.0 END - ((SIZE/128.0) - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(a.name, ''SPACEUSED'') AS INT)/128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
            ROW_SPACEUSED = CAST(CASE WHEN a.type_desc = ''ROWS'' THEN fileproperty(a.name, ''spaceused'') END / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
            LOG_SPACEUSED = CAST(CASE WHEN a.type_desc = ''LOG'' THEN fileproperty(a.name, ''spaceused'') END / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2)),
            CASE WHEN a.type_desc = ''ROWS'' THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN growth = 0 THEN CAST(size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
                    WHEN max_size / 128.0 < 0 and growth > 0 THEN 0
                    ELSE CAST(max_size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
                END
                END AS row_maxsize,
                
            CASE WHEN a.type_desc = ''ROWS'' THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN max_size = -1 and growth > 0 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
                END AS hasNegativeMaxSize,
                
                CASE 
                WHEN a.type_desc = ''LOG'' THEN CAST(max_size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2))
                ELSE 0.0
            END as max_logsize


        FROM sys.database_files a
        LEFT JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON a.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id
    )
    SELECT
        DB_NAME() AS database_name,
        SUM(ALLOCATED_LOG_SIZE_MB),
        SUM(ALLOCATED_ROW_SIZE_MB),
        SUM(ALLOCATED_TOTAL_SIZE_MB),
        SUM(USED_ROW_SPACE_MB),
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(hasNegativeMaxSize) = 1 THEN 0
            ELSE NULLIF(SUM(row_maxsize), 0)
        END AS MAX_ROW_SIZE,
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(hasNegativeMaxSize) = 1 THEN 0
            ELSE SUM(ROW_SPACEUSED) / NULLIF(SUM(row_maxsize), 0) * 100
        END AS MAX_ROW_UTILIZATION,
        SUM(LOG_SPACEUSED) / NULLIF(SUM(max_logsize), 0) * 100
    FROM CTE;
    ';

    SELECT * FROM @temp_dbspace_solaire;
END;
```

It returns several errors

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
> Invalid column name 'ALLOCATED_LOG_SIZE_MB'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
> Invalid column name 'ALLOCATED_ROW_SIZE_MB'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
> Invalid column name 'ALLOCATED_TOTAL_SIZE_MB'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
> Invalid column name 'USED_ROW_SPACE_MB'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 42
> Invalid column name 'hasNegativeMaxSize'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
> Invalid column name 'row_maxsize'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 43
> Invalid column name 'row_maxsize'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
> Invalid column name 'hasNegativeMaxSize'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 47

Comment: sp_msforeachdb accepts parameter as nvarchar(2000), your query is 2300 chars or so. you should really use something else for looping database, or just write your own loop, it's not too hard

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks, I remove some others line of the code and the case works now, seem to be the limitation of 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_MSforeachdb` is [known to have many issues](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/). Your issue happens to be that it's [defined](https://dbfiddle.uk/bXFt0e2m) with a parameter `@command1 nvarchar(2000)` which is too small for your command.

While there are workarounds, it's much better to just redo the whole thing from scratch.

You can write a cursor loop that can do your command as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @crsr CURSOR;
SET @crsr = CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.sp_executesql'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.database_id > 4;  -- not system

OPEN @crsr;
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT @crsr INTO @proc;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        BREAK;

    EXEC @proc @sql;  -- add parameters as necessary
END;
```

You can also obviate the need for a cursor and a temp table at all, by constructing one big query and executing it.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST('
SELECT
  ' + QUOTENAME(name, '''') + ' AS databaseName,
  --whatever
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.file_groups
' AS nvarchar(max)), '
UNION ALL
')

FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.database_id > 4;  -- not system

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

It gets more complicated to use this second option when CTEs are involved, but you should still be able to manage it.